# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "hermes-engine"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

After updating the React Native version, I'm unable to reinstall pod dependencies.

Error output:

Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Installing unimodules:
expo-application@3.1.2 from ../node_modules/expo-application/ios
expo-constants@10.1.3 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
expo-error-recovery@2.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
expo-file-system@11.0.2 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
expo-font@9.3.0 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
expo-image-loader@2.1.1 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
expo-json-utils@0.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-json-utils/ios
expo-keep-awake@9.1.2 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
expo-manifests@0.4.0 from ../node_modules/expo-manifests/ios
expo-modules-core@0.3.2 from ../node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios
expo-permissions@12.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
expo-splash-screen@0.14.2 from ../node_modules/expo-app-loading/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
expo-structured-headers@3.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-structured-headers/ios
expo-updates-interface@0.8.1 from ../node_modules/expo-updates-interface/ios
unimodules-app-loader@2.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios
unimodules-camera-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios
unimodules-constants-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios
unimodules-core@7.1.2 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
unimodules-face-detector-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios
unimodules-file-system-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios
unimodules-font-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios
unimodules-image-loader-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios
unimodules-permissions-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios
unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.2.2 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
unimodules-sensors-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios
unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:
expo-font, expo-splash-screen

warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `Bufunfa`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNLocalize, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, and react-native-safe-area-context
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes/hermes-engine.podspec`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "hermes-engine":
In Podfile:
hermes-engine (from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes/hermes-engine.podspec`)

Specs satisfying the `hermes-engine (from` ../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes/hermes-engine.podspec`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I tried   upgrade ruby verssion and   pod update hermes-engine --no-repo-update  but noting  changes

Answer (score 15):

I executed this command in ios folder.. worked for me..

`pod update hermes-engine --no-repo-update`

Comment: Minor point: The command needs to be run inside ios folder

Comment: Any explanation why this works? And why it is only the hermes-engine dependency that is causing this issue?

Comment: it didn't help to me

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue, just deleted `podfile.lock` and
run `pod install` again.
It resolved my problem.

Comment: While that might fix the issue, it will also have other unintended effects, namely losing all previously locked (and guaranteed to be working) versions of pod dependencies. Always be wary when someone suggests "delete the lock file" as a fix...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Expo and `eas build`, you can run this code to build without a cache:

```
eas build --clear-cache
```

Alternatively, you can update your `eas.json` file with a cache key so that it builds cleanly:

```
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "cache": {
        "key": "whatever" // <- set this
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ended up disabling the cache altogether for some builds; but the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue when `eas build`, just deleted the directory of `ios` and executed `eas build` again. It resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my ruby version using rvm to ruby-3.2.2, so maybe try using the version of ruby you created your podfile on.
Then run:

> `pod update hermes-engine --no-repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

[Referencing this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3076#issuecomment-571973978) for others.

> Try deleting your ios/Podfile.lock and re-rerunning the pod install command?